# Functional equation of function defined over non-negative reals satisfying $f \big(xf(y)\big)f(y)=f(x+y)$, $f(2)=0$ and $f(x)\ne0$ for $x\in[0, 2)$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all $ f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty) $ such that $ f (2)=0 $, $ f (x)\ne 0 $ for $ x\in [0, 2) $ and
> $$ f \bigl(xf (y)\bigr) f (y)=f (x+y) $$
> for all $ x, y\ge 0 $.

I tried plugging in values of $ x $ and $ y $ but didn't succeed.

Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: This is from the IMO 1986, [Problem 5](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asdas/imo/imo/isoln/isoln865.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [determining every function $f$ defined for positive numbers satisfying $f\big(xf(y)\big)f(y)=f(x+y)$, $f(2)=0$ and $f(x)\ne 0$ for $0\le x&lt;2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913593/determining-every-function-f-defined-for-positive-numbers-satisfying-f-bigxf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute in $x=y=0$, we get that $ f(0) f(0) = f(0)$. Since $f(0) \neq 0$, thus $f(0) = 1$.

Substitute in $x=x, y = 2$, $0 = f(x\cdot 0) \cdot 0 = f(x+2)$. Hence for $x \geq 2, f(x) = 0 $.

We now focus our attention to the region $x\leq 2$.

Substitute in $x=2-y, y = y < 2$. We get that $ f[ (2-y) f(y) ] f(y) = f(2) = 0$. Since $f(y) \neq 0$ thus $(2-y) f(y) \geq 2$, or that $f(y) \geq \frac{2}{2-y}$.

Suppose that there exists a value $y$ such that $f(y) > \frac{2}{2-y}$. Then, take the value $x$ such that $ \frac{2}{f(y)} < x < 2-y$. We get that

$$ 0 = f( x f(y) ) f(y) = f(x+y) \neq  0,$$

which is a contradiction. Hence, at best, $f(y) = \frac{2}{2-y}$.

It is easy to check that $ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{2}{2-x}& 0\leq x < 2 \\ 0 & 2 \leq x \\ \end{cases}$ is a solution to the functional equation. (The simplest approach is to condition on $x+y<2$ and $x+y \geq 2$). Hence, it is the only solution.