# determining every function $f$ defined for positive numbers satisfying $f\big(xf(y)\big)f(y)=f(x+y)$, $f(2)=0$ and $f(x)\ne 0$ for $0\le x<2$

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

determine every function $f$ defined for positive numbers , having positive values, such that:

- $f\big(xf(y)\big)f(y)=f(x+y)$;
- $f(2)=0$;
- $f(x)\ne 0$ for every $0\le x<2$.

I proved that $f(x)=0$ for every $x$ greater than $2$

Comment: Does this answer your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660662/to-find-all-functions-f-0-infty-rightarrow-0-infty-such-that-fxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1.** Substitution $y = 2$ gives $f(x+2) = 0$, so $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \ge 2$. Since $f(x) \neq 0$ for $0\le x < 2$ we conclude 
$$
f(x) = 0 \iff x \ge 2.
$$

**Step 2.** Substitution $x \to 2 - x$ and $y \to x$ gives 
$$
f((2-x)f(x))f(x) = 0,
$$
so for $0\le x < 2$ (since $f(x) \neq 0$) we have $f((2-x)f(x)) = 0$ or (by step 1)  $(2-x)f(x) \ge 2$, so
$$
f(x) \ge \frac{2}{2-x}  \iff 0\le x < 2.
$$

**Step 3.** Substitution $x \to \frac{2}{f(x)}$ and $y \to x$ gives for $x < 2$
$$
0 = f\left(\frac{2}{f(x)}f\left(x\right)\right)f\left(x\right) = f\left(\frac{2}{f(x)} + x\right),
$$
so by step 1 
$$
x + \frac{2}{f(x)} \ge 2
$$
which implies 
$$
f(x) \le \frac{2}{2-x}.
$$
Comparing this with result of step 2 we get, finally 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{2}{2-x}, & 0\le x < 2, \\
0, & 2 \le x.
\end{cases}
$$